# Debian network setting are ignored

Tags: linux, networking, debian, static-ip, debian-bookworm

I already looked through the internet (and StackExchange ;) ) but did not find a working solution yet. So (yet another) question about non-working networksettings :)

I don't get, why my wired interface (on this system its called end0, not eth0) does not use the configured static ip address (192.168.57.222) but gets some other (192.168.57.45). For my wireless interface wlan0 (192.168.57.223) it is working.

Can somebody please take a look on my settings and outputs and tell me what's wrong?

The assigned ip addresses:

```
~# hostname -I
 192.168.57.45 192.168.57.223 [ipv6-address]
```

Output of ifconfig

```
~# ifconfig 
 end0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.57.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.57.255
        inet6 XXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 XXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 145  bytes 18385 (17.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 50  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 81  bytes 12484 (12.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 21  bytes 2432 (2.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21  bytes 2432 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
 wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.57.223  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.57.255
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xy  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3764  bytes 363905 (355.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2971  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 272  bytes 32838 (32.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The interfaces file is empty, uncommenting the end0 settings here does not change the behavior:

```
~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
#source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
#auto end0
#allow-hotplug end0
#iface end0 inet static
# address 192.168.57.222
# netmask 255.255.255.0
# gateway 192.168.57.1
# dns-domain my.domain
# dns-nameservers 192.168.57.6
```

The dhcpcd.conf (without comments). The ipv6 stuff should avoid such problems as I have says the internet. nodhcp should "not talk to dhcp" and rebind should reread the config and restart the services on changes, as far as I understood the manpage.

```
~# cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

hostname
clientid
#duid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option interface_mtu
#option ntp_servers
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

#my changes:
noipv6rs
noipv6
nodhcp
rebind

interface end0
static ip_address=192.168.57.222/24
static routers=192.168.57.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.57.1
static domain_search=my.domain

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.57.223/24
static routers=192.168.57.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.57.6
static domain_search=my.domain
```

Service states:

```
~# service dhcpcd status
○ dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)

~# service networking status
○ networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
```

My Distro-Settings

```
~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
```